# Why does my Terminal writes different device than my Mac?

Tags: angularjs, angular, macos, command-line, terminal

I am pretty new to Command Line so my question might be silly. However, when I use Terminal, the first line says:

```
Last login: Thu Nov 30 18:05:56 on console
android-14441fd69c900692:~ user$
```

instead of

```
Last login: Thu Nov 30 18:05:56 on console
MyMacbookPro:~ user$
```

- Does it have any effect on the commands?
- Should I change it back to MyMacbooPro as it used to be?
- If yes then how?
- Can it be the reason why I get the following error message when I try to start launching server for my Angular application by using `ng serve --o`? (it used to work before the name changed, that's the reason I asked this)

The error message I get:

```
Cannot find module 'copy-webpack-plugin'
Error: Cannot find module 'copy-webpack-plugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/common.js:5:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/index.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not have any effect on the commands.
You don't have to change it back. The issue you are reporting is due to something else. However, if you want to change the login prompt, you need to add `export PS1="MyMacbookPro"` to your `.profile` in your home directory `/Users/<user_name>` (assuming you don't have `.bash_profile` yet)